# Create a database-service in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

I am developing a web-application using java and spring-boot on AWS Lambda Service.
I am designing it to have one database-service. This will be collections of Entity(table) and JPARepositories classes. So If I need to have any database schema changes I just have to make the change only in this service.

The other services which will be exposed through an API-gateway will be using this database-service as a Lambda Layer.

```
parent-project 
|
|---database-service
|
|---API-service1
|
|---API-service2
...
```

The Problem is I need to create the tables before any of the Lambda Service is deployed. So that this API-Services can use them. One way to solve this is to deploy the database-service as a Lambda function and invoke the function which will call a method like below to create all the tables.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DatabaseServiceApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    private final AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB;

    public DatabaseServiceApplication(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB) {
        this.amazonDynamoDB = amazonDynamoDB;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DatabaseServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
        public void run(String... strings) {
            dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);
            CreateTableRequest tableRequest = dynamoDBMapper
                    .generateCreateTableRequest(Association.class);
            tableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(
                    new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L));
            TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(amazonDynamoDB, tableRequest);
        }
}
```

Or use a script to create the tables. I am not sure which is a better option or is there any better option.

Can anyone suggest me if anyone has faced this problem before and fixed it?

Comment: How are you managing deployments? If you were using something like CloudFormation or Terraform you could have that create the DynamoDB tables for you instead of relying on Java code to do that.

Comment: I am using Terraform for deploying my Lambda function and integrating with api-gateway.

Comment: @MarkB - Can u suggest me a way by which I can rely on my java code to create the tables rather than using a script?

Comment: By database service do you mean DynamoDB or RDS? You mentioned schema changes.

Comment: @LLL - DynamoDB

Answer (score 2):

To me the best way to do this is on Lambda cold start.  Your code needs to be smart enough to not care if the DB is already correct.  Based on the code you're showing I would do something on the order of:

```
public class LambdaExample implements RequestStreamHandler {

    // only called on cold start
    public LambdaExample() {
        dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB);
        CreateTableRequest tableRequest = dynamoDBMapper
                .generateCreateTableRequest(Association.class);
        tableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(
                new ProvisionedThroughput(1L, 1L));
        TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(amazonDynamoDB, tableRequest);
    }

    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {
        // handle request.  this lambda type requires reading the inputStream
        // yourself but use whatever you normally have here.
    }
```

If you're using a traditional relational database, you could use [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) instead.  It too knows if a DB has already been updated.

Note that if you have thousands of Lambdas they will all call this, slowing the cold start of every single one of them.  That is why @MarkB is suggesting a process to externalize the DB creation as really only the very first Lambda kicked off does anything useful.  After that you're wasting a bit of time/money with every new Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are deploying via Terraform then the correct way to do this is to [have Terraform create the DynamoDB tables as well](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/dynamodb_table.html). You would configure your `aws_lambda_function` resources in Terraform with `depends_on` property referencing the `aws_dynamodb_table` resource, so that Terraform would ensure the table is created before the Lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please answer the below questions? 
1) Are you deploying your springboot application in lambda? 
If Yes, that doesn't sound like a good use of Springboot, Springboot application should be hosted in EC2/ECS instance to be up and running (24/7).
Think about Lambda as a function that runs to handle a simple task. To achieve that, you can write a simple Java application, and deploy the jar to lambda function.

2) CloudFormation, TerraForm and other languages are used to create the infrastructure, you usually run the infrastructure job first, and the deployment after it.

Here's a link of a terraform structure I built for a personal project. 
https://github.com/saifmasadeh/terraform-project-structure